# Can anyone explain what the code putchar('/' //*/ 1) mean

Tags: c, putchar

I was doing the exercise of the K&R2. When i was reading the code by Ben Pfaff in this page http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_23  I coudn't understand what the single code putchar('/' //*/ 1) mean. While in my compiler, it is a syntax error. So can anyone explain this to me.

Comment: That's a comment and a division operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the comments at the beginning of the solution it explains why you're seeing that error:

> It also contains examples of a comment that ends    in a star and a
>   comment preceded by a slash.  Note that the latter    will break C99
>   compilers and C89 compilers with // comment    extensions.

In a compiler that does not support `//` style comments, this:

```
putchar('/' //**/ 
        1)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
putchar('/'/1)
```

Which is legal -- though odd -- expression (remember that in C a `char` is a numeric type, so `'/'/1` is the same as `/`).  This happens because the sequence `/**/` is an empty comment.

In a modern compiler with `//` style comments, the expression ends up being equivalent to:

```
puchar('/' 1)
```

Which is simply an error.

Comment: Sorry to ask this silly question, actually i did read the comment by the author.But as a foreign student, my English is actually not so good and i didn't understand that sentence. Now i do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, the original code is placed in multiple lines, like so:

```
    putchar('/' //**/
            1);
```

From here, /**/ part is a comment, so after pre-processing, the code would look like this:

putchar('/' / 1);

Which is equal to putchar('/');

You are getting compiler error because you are compiling this code either as C99 or, most likely, as C++, where // is a single-line comment. Compile as C89 instead.

Sorry for bad formatting - writing from my phone...